# How do I append to an XML file in java

Tags: java, xml

```
public void XMLWrite(String id, String firstname, String lastname, String address, String phonenumber, String email,
        String dateofbirth, String profession, String organization, int test) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        Element rootElement;
        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();

            if (test == 1)
                // add elements to Document
                rootElement = doc.createElement( "Personal-Contact-List");
            else
                rootElement = doc.createElement( "Business-Contact-List");
            // append root element to document
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            // append first child element to root element
            if (test == 1)
                rootElement.appendChild(
                        getContact(doc, id, firstname, lastname, address, phonenumber, email, dateofbirth, null, null, test));
            else
                rootElement.appendChild(getContact(doc, id, firstname, lastname, address, phonenumber, email, null,
                        profession, organization, test));

            // for output to file, console
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            // for pretty print
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

            StreamResult file;
            if (test == 1)
                file = new StreamResult(new File("PersonalContactList.xml"));
            else
                file = new StreamResult(new File("BusinessContactList.xml"));

            // write data
            transformer.transform(source, file);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Node getContact(Document doc, String id, String firstname, String lastname, String address,
            String phonenumber, String email, String dateofbirth, String profession, String organization, int test) {
        Element employee = doc.createElement("Personal-Contact");

        // set id attribute
        employee.appendChild(getContactElements(doc, employee, "id", id));

        // create name element
        employee.appendChild(getContactElements(doc, employee, "firstname", firstname));

        // create age element
        employee.appendChild(getContactElements(doc, employee, "lastname", lastname));

        // create role element
        employee.appendChild(getContactElements(doc, employee, "address", address));

        // create gender element
        employee.appendChild(getContactElements(doc, employee, "phoneNumber", phonenumber));

        employee.appendChild(getContactElements(doc, employee, "email", email));

        if(test == 1){
        employee.appendChild(getContactElements(doc, employee, "dateofBirth", dateofbirth));
            }else {
        employee.appendChild(getContactElements(doc, employee, "profession", profession));

        employee.appendChild(getContactElements(doc, employee, "organization", organization));
            }

        return employee;
    }

    // utility method to create text node
    private static Node getContactElements(Document doc, Element element, String name, String value) {
        Element node = doc.createElement(name);
        node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value));
        return node;
    }
```

I'm trying to add data to an XML file, I've copied all the data to an ArrayList of contacts added my new contact then tried to write again to the XML file, but it only creates 1 contact in the file and overwrite with the latest available contact data.

```
public static void XMLWrite(int test) {
    if (test == 1) {
        for (PersonalContact PC : PClist) {
            xml.XMLWrite(PC.getContactId(), PC.getFirstName(), PC.getLastName(), PC.getAddress(),
                    PC.getPhoneNumber(), PC.getEmailAddress(), PC.getDateofBirth(), null, null, test);
        }
    } else {
        for (BusinessContact BC : BClist) {
            xml.XMLWrite(BC.getContactId(), BC.getFirstName(), BC.getLastName(), BC.getAddress(),
                    BC.getPhoneNumber(), BC.getEmailAddress(), null, BC.getJobTitle(), BC.getOrganization(), test);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?! I can't get it the add new contacts to the XML file.

Comment: Are you trying to append to an existing document? It looks like you are creating a new document and adding the new contact info without appending the old contact info first.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I'm trying to append to an existing document

Comment: If you haven't figured it out yet, you need to load the existing document & append to it. Right now, you are loading a new document and appending to it. If you want the new document to contain data from the old document, you gotta copy it over. Can't expect the old document data to be there when you never copy it over to the new document you are creating.